# Can't disconnect from bonded BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, microchip, disconnect

I'm creating application on Android where I have to talk with Microchip's RN4020 Bluetooth Low Energy module. I have to create bond with this module to exchange data and everything was working fine few days ago.

Now yesterday from nowhere I noticed that if I lost connection or terminated connection intentionally with RN4020 I couldn't reconnect to it because to reconnect in my application I have to 1st listen for direct advertisement which is happening only if device is not connected at the given moment. I checked using UART what info my RN4020 is giving me. If I didn't bond devices and connected/disconnected multiple times UART gave me

> Connected
>
> Connection End
>
> Connected
>
> Connection End
>
> Connected
>
> Connection End
>
> ...

Now If I bonded devices, the same code gave me me only

> Connected

Even though `Android Monitor` tab in `Android Studio` confirmed that disconnection and closing `BluetoothGatt` is done, my RN4020 didn't agree with that.

I also downloaded another free application from `Play Store` which can connect to BLE devices and read/write characteristics. Same thing happened there. If bond is not created with RN4020 I can connect and disconnect as many times I want without problems but when bond is created my phone just stays connnected to RN4020 unless I turn off Bluetooth completely. Then after turning it back on I can catch its direct advertising but when I connect I again can't disconnect.

Can anyone give me any idea whats going on?

---

**EDIT :** One more thing - When I go to `Application Manager` on my phone (Galaxy S4 active / Lolipop), click to Running -> Bluetooth I can see it kind of states 1 process and 11 services are running. One of these services are `BleAutoConnectService`. But anyway it doesn't change anything if I turn it off.

---

**EDIT nr 2 :** When I yesterday tested it with my friends Sony Xperia (I think it was `Z`) this happened : When creating fresh bond with RN4020 I got the following messages on UART

> Connected
>                                                   ConnParam: 0006,0000,07D0
>                                                      Bonded
>                                                       ConnParam: 0027,0000,07D0
>                                                       ConnParam: 0006,0000,07D0
>                                                       ConnParam: 0027,0000,07D0
>                                                         Connection End

so at least that phone got disconnected after bonding. This is what datasheet says about `ConnParam`:

> When connected and connection parameters are updated by the  peer
>   device, message “ConnParam” is sent to the UART. Message  “ConnParam”
>   has three 16-bit parameters, which are connection  interval, slave
>   latency and supervision timeout respectively.

and when I sent **'D'** command to RN4020 to display critical information about it, it gave me

> Bonded=FFFFFFFFFFFF,**1**    //1 stands for private/random MAC address

but **with my device** I was just getting

> Connected
>   Bonded

and **'D'** command gave me

> Bonded=FFFFFFFFFFFF,**0**    //0 stands for public MAC address

**So yesterday I decided to sleep on it but today everything works just fine. I can connect and disconnect whether devices are bonded or not from my own phone how many times I want.** I have no clue why is this happening and what to do with this random behavior.

Comment: Which Android device model do you have? Have you tried another Android device to see if the behaviour is the same?

Comment: I have had some similiar problems with the RN4871 module. I solved it with a 1 uFcapacitor (really close!!) at the power supply pins of the module. Also have a look a the reset of your module. The microchip BLE modules are sometimes really tricky.

Comment: I'm using Galaxy S4 active which has android lolipop. Havent checked it for different devices but will definitely do today. Weird thing is that when creating bond lets say before 2 weeks my phone connected to RN4020 / bonded / disconnected but now also when just creating bond it just connects and bonds. This is even without using a single line of code from my app

Comment: @Mike I cant really try it out right now because I have jump wires soldered to RN4020 and they are then plugged into a breadboard and I don't have a soldering hammer available to me right now, but I will give it a try when I can. Thanks for suggestion :)